# Target Clean does not exist in the project dir

Tags: ant, build, build-process

I have installed Ant in my `centos 6.3` , installed location are
`/opt/ant` and also `ANT_HOME` env are same

I have created `build.xml` to test by deleting `testdir`. This directory exist in the `/opt/ant/testdir` like this.

## build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="testdir" default="all" basedir=".">
  <property name="src"   value="src"/>
    <property name="build" value="build"/>
      <property name="lib"   value="lib"/>

    <target name="all" depends="clean, compile" description="Builds the whole project">
        <echo>Doing all</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <echo message="Deleting bin/java ..." />
        <delete dir="testdir/test" />
    </target>
</project>
```

**Using Command :-**

```
    ant -buildfile build.xml Clean
```

**getting error:-**

```
    BUILD FAILED
    Target "Clean" does not exist in the project "testdir".
```

Any suggestion to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution. I missed `target="compile"` block in `build.xml`.

```
<target name="compile">
    <echo message="Compiling source code"/>
</target>
```

Run command :-

```
ant clean
```

Answer (score 4):

You mis-spelt the target name ? 'Clean' as against 'clean' ??

Comment: I have tried you solution. getting error `Target "compile" does not exist in the project "testdir". It is used from target "all".`